# Core Rulebook v2.1 - Damage to a mob of troops

Tags: damage, defense, wrath-and-glory

The Core Rulebook for Wrath & Glory 2nd edition explains the rules when battling a mob of troop-level enemies this way:

> ##### MOB DAMAGE
>
> Mobs are only made up of Troops, and every individual in a Mob has 1 Wound. If your attack deals more damage than a Mob’s Resilience, your target dies.
>
> The number of Icons rolled on an attack Test determines how many individuals in the Mob are hit. Every Icon rolled over the Mob’s Defence means an additional individual in the Mob is hit.
>
> Every individual Threat in a Mob has the same Maximum Shock. If a Mob suffers more Shock damage
> than their Maximum Shock, one individual in the Mob is removed. If a Test to inflict Shock damage exceeds the Mob’s Defence, it hits multiple individuals, as with a normal attack.
>
> > *Example: Yasmin fires her Boltgun at a Mob of ten Aeldari Guardian Defenders. She rolls 6 Icons on her Ballistic Skill Test, and the Mob of Guardians has a Defence of 3. Yasmin hits 4 Guardians with the attack — one for rolling 3 Icons and equalling the Mob’s Defence, and an additional +1 for every Icon rolled over the Mob’s Defence.
> >
> > The Boltgun deals 10 Damage, more than enough to deal 1 Wound to the Mob. All four Guardians die.*

In the example, the mob is a troop of Aeldari Guardian Defenders, with a Resilience value of 6, a Defense value of 3, a Wounds value of 4 and a Shock value of 3.

Does it mean that any weapon with 6+ (or 7+?) damage would have killed the same number of defenders in the troop?

Also, how much Maximum Shock does the Mob have in this case and how do the players inflict Shock to the Mob?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but here's how I understand the use of each "defensive" stat in a Mob:

- **Resilience** : HP threshold to overcome for a kill
- **Defense** : Chances to hit
- **Wounds** : Unused, replaced by a base value of 1
- **Shock** : No idea...

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is the case that any weapon that deals 7 or more damage is going to kill every Aeldari Guardian that it hits.  If it matches exactly, it instead produces one shock per individual hit.  If that results in an amount of shock greater than the Shock value (3) then one individual is removed.

It appears to be the case that damage is only rolled against a mob one time for a single attack.  Thus, if you were attacking the previously mentioned mob of Aeldari, you got 6 successes on your ballistic test, your weapon was dealing 6+ and you rolled at least one success on the extra damage dice, then you'd kill four.  If you rolled no successes on the extra damage dice, you'd deal 4 shock, thus eliminating one.  On the other hand, if you were attempting to murder them with a spear (Str+3, ED 3) and did not have the strength to back it up, you could easily wind up rolling under 6 damage, and doing nothing at all.

Additionally, some attacks (certain psychic powers, for example) deal shock directly.  Mobs are a particularly inefficient target for such things, but it would work.  It does not appear that Mobs are intended to track shock on a round to round basis.

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have missed the rule where dealing the same amount of Damage as the Resilience converts to Wounds.